# How do make this code responsive in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

How do make the code below responsive. I wanted the second Column to collapse under the first and  the third column to collapse under the second. Or make it responsive enough that everything can fit in a phone screen. Currently. It would work fine for tablet or computer screen.

```
class Sample extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SampleState createState() => _SampleState();
}

class _SampleState extends State<Sample> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('sample'),
      ),
      body: Container(
        height: 200,
        width: 2000,
        color: Color(0xff808080),
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
          children: [
            Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Text('Contact Us'),
                Row(children: [
                  Icon(Icons.phone),
                  Text('phone')]),
                Row(children: [
                  Icon(Icons.mail),
                  Text('info@test.it')]),
                Row(children: [
                  Icon(Icons.map_outlined),
                  Text('unavailable')]),
              ],
            ),
            Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Text('Contact Us'),
                Icon(Icons.wrap_text_rounded),
                Icon(Icons.point_of_sale),
              ],
            ),
            Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Text('Newsletter'),
                Text('Susbcribe'),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many choices for making a flutter app responsive.  The best description is Google's own writing at https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/layout/responsive, which suggests

- LayoutBuilder
- MediaQuery.of()
- AspectRatio
- CustomSingleChildLayout
- CustomMultiChildLayout
- FittedBox
- FractionallySizedBox
- LayoutBuilder
- MediaQuery
- MediaQueryData
- OrientationBuilder

As some of the many ways to write code that is responsive.

Comment: Yes Randal, those widgets you listed can be used to make your site or map more responsive. But, I mention something more specific. I am new to the platform. I just do not know how to do it in flutter.

Comment: I used layoutBuilder to format the code above. However, I had to make some adjustments. I had remove the main row because it would not be responsive.